# How can I get packets data from AudioStream Android?

Tags: android

I'm writing a audio wave from [AudioStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/rtp/AudioStream.html). My abstract code like this:

```
public void audio_Wave(AudioStream){
    for(packet : get_Packets_From_AudioStream){
        draw_Wave(packet)
    }
}
```

How can I get each packet from AudioStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I believe you are trying to do, you may want to consider looking into Visualizer. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html
You can also see a sample [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/02/create-audio-visualizer-for-mediaplayer.html)

Comment: is there any way can I take the raw data byte audio before I send a packet to the other side?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by send it to the other side, but you can use onDataCaptureListener to get the raw byte data https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener.html